# Transpose a string in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm very new to Pascal and still learning much. I have to write a code that :

1. Takes input of a string
2. Split the string into two characters each (Snippet)
3. Use the Snippet to get an index from an array
4. Transpose the Snippet to a certain value
5. If Index + Transpose is larger than the length of the Array, return nothing
6. If not, append the transposed Snippet to a result string
7. Return the transposed string

I can only write 1 through 3, the rest is still a blur for me. Helps are appreciated.

(And I also want to improve it without many `for` loops. Any thoughts?)

```
program TransposeString;

var
  melody : Array[1..24] of String[2] = ('c.', 'c#', 'd.', 'd#', 'e.', 'f.', 'f#', 'g.', 'g#', 'a.', 'a#', 'b.', 'C.', 'C#', 'D.', 'D#', 'E.', 'F.', 'F#', 'G.', 'G#', 'A.', 'A#', 'B.');
  songstring, transposedstring : String;
  transposevalue : byte;

function Transpose(song : String; transposevalue : byte): String;

var
  songsnippet : String[2];
  iter_song, iter_index, index : byte;

begin
  for iter_song := 1 to length(song) do
  begin
    if iter_song mod 2 = 0 then continue;
    songsnippet := song[iter_song] + song[iter_song + 1]; //Split the string into 2 characters each

    for iter_index := 1 to 24 do
    begin
      if melody[iter_index] = songsnippet then
      begin
        index := iter_index; //Get Index
        break;
      end;
    end;
    //Check Transpose + Index
    //Transpose Snippet
    //Append Snippet to Result String
  end;
end;

begin
  readln(songstring);
  readln(transposevalue);
  transposedstring := transpose(songstring, transposevalue);
  writeln(transposedstring);
end.
```

Comment: transpose in this context is a musical term, to change notes to a different key or register.   Probably simply add the transposevalue and check for wraparound.

Comment: For me, the vague part of your description is #5: `If Index + Transpose is larger than the length of the Array, return nothing`. Do you mean return nothing as the result of transposition of that particular snippet and go on to the next one or do you mean break the process entirely and return an empty string as the result of the Transpose function? Other than that, what @Marco has said makes perfect sense to me. Use the implicitly declared Result variable (in Transpose) to construct the resulting string.

Comment: @AndriyM return nothing means break the process entirely, so it only returns an empty string as the result.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter for you to work from, rather than just spoon-feeding an answer:

You have the index of the snippet (note) in index. Assuming the notes are in order you need to return the note from the array  positions above it, so

```
result := result + melody[iter_index + transposevalue];
```

You need to check the length of the array before trying to read from it, otherwise it'll crash (step 5). This is just an `if` statement.

I wouldn't worry too much about for loops - 2 deep nesting isn't that bad. If you wanted to split it out a bit then `GetTransposedNote(const note:string): string;` could be split out as a new function.

Things you may want to think about are:

- What if you can't find the note in the array?
- Do you want to be case-sensitive
- What if the input string has an odd number of characters?

You are most of the way there already, though.